# Why my child process exit without actual termination?

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I am writing a program about process

The process accept a bash command and run it with exec

I use fork() to create child process run exec inside it

and plan to do some post process in parent process

but for some reason the exec run properly but wait is not working poperly

"post process here" print put before exec's program terminate

It worked before but suddenly not working,

I have not idea what changes I have made to cause this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* code */

  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    //delete argv 0 for convincent
    argv[i] = argv[i + 1];
  }

  int pid = fork();
  if(pid == -1){
    return 1;
  }

  if(pid == 0){
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
  }else{
    wait(NULL);
    printf("post process here");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When something is working, save a version in your version control system (you are using one, aren't you?). Go back to the previously working version. Work out what you changed. You've not shown what command line options you are providing to your program. You aren't handling any errors. You aren't capturing the information returned by `wait()`. You should finish your  `printf()` statement with a newline. There's no need to play games with `argv` as you do. You could use `execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);` instead. You should report an error and exit with a non-zero status when (if) `execvp()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
//delete argv 0 for convincent
    argv[i] = argv[i + 1];
```

i would us a new array with bound [argc+1] otherwise you are in danger of an array out of bound error (bufferoverflow).

Second:
the called bash command is important. Some commands are just starting a deamon and finish themself.